# how can i access current location from web-page in react native webview

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview, remote-debugging

I have an app which developed in react-js. I want to integrate this app into [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview). everything I right but I have two problems.
1-**how can I access current location of the user in react-native-webview.**
2-**how can I debug my react-js(webpage) app inside react-native-webview.**

**for first problem**
if I run webpage in a mobile browser and click on that event I'm getting current location of the user and at the same time when my **react-native app** getting started, I'm invoking permission for current location so in `react-native-debugger` i'm getting current location of user.i followed the similar example but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52715563/9623598) is related to react-native.
**exact problem is how can I access the current location of webview in react-native-webview**

**for second problem**
when I'm clicking on the event to fetch current location it is not showing the current location so ** I want to see what is error/response of that event**. because it is in webview I can access react-native logs in react-native-debugger but cannot see the web view logs in the debugger.I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572797/9623598) one also but I don't know where to put that android config code.

my **react-native** code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    // To see all the requests in the chrome Dev tools in the network tab.
    XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest ?
    GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest :
    GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;

    // fetch logger
    global._fetch = fetch;
    global.fetch = function (uri, options, ...args) {
    return global._fetch(uri, options, ...args).then((response) => {
    console.log('Fetch', { request: { uri, options, ...args }, response });
    return response;
});
};
}
async requestLocationPermission() {
    try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
        'title': 'Location Access Permission',
        'message': 'Stanplus would like to use your location ' +
                    'so you we track you.'
        }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can use the location");
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.navigator !== 'undefined' && navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
            console.log(position.coords.latitude,'success');
            },
            (error) => {
            console.log(error,'fail')
            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 10000 }
        );
        }


    } else {
        console.log("Location permission denied")
    }
    } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
    }


}

componentDidMount() {
        this.requestLocationPermission();
    }

render() {
    return (
    <WebView 
        source={{uri: 'https://3fa4f958.ngrok.io/steptwo'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
        onMessage={(event)=> console.log(event.nativeEvent.data)}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
    javaScriptEnabled = {true}
    />
    );
}
}
```

my **React.js** code which accesses current location

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        alert('event clicked');//in react-native app its showing the alert
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        //but inside here react-native can't execute because of location permission issue
        position => {   
                let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                let geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
                //do other stuff----------
            }
        )
}
```

** I want to fetch current location when user click on webpage event inside react-native app and how to debug webview code**

please help stuck since 2 days ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `geolocationenabled`  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#geolocationenabled

Comment: can someone update the link, it is no longer valid.

Comment: Webview removed from the core. it's here now but the same prop. https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#geolocationenabled

Answer (score 11):

A few steps are needed to get it working on Android.

Add this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And then in your app you'll need to request location once before the webview can request it. Do it like so in your view:

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

...

PermissionsAndroid.request(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
  {
    title: 'Location Access Permission',
    message: 'We would like to use your location',
    buttonPositive: 'Okay'
  }
);
```

And then also on your webview add the property:

```
geolocationEnabled={true}
```